# Why I can´t import a class in python?

Tags: python

This is my folder structure:

```
├── Basic
├── Coche
│   ├── __init.py__
│   ├── coche.py
├── miPrimerCoche.py
```

I want to import the class "coche.py" in miPrimerCoche.
In coche.py I have this:

```
class Coche:

    def __init__(self, marca, color, caballos):
        self.marca = marca
        self.color = color
        self.caballos = caballos

    def datos(self):
        return "Este coche es un: " + self.marca + \
           " de color: " + self.color + " y con: " + str(self.caballos)    + " caballos"
```

And, in miPrimerCoche I have this code:

```
from Coche import coche

miMercedes = coche("Toyota", "verde", 50)
print miMercedes.marca
print miMercedes.datos()
```

Then, when I run miPrimerCoche, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "/Users/personalUser/PycharmProjects/untitled/Basic/importar_clase.py",    line 3, in <module>
    miMercedes = coche("Toyota", "verde", 50)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Basic is the src folder (it is in blue color), what I can do?

I resolved with

```
  miMercedes = coche.Coche(par1, par2, par3...)
```

but I don´t know if is the good way to do it.

Comment: Did you try importing the class?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from coche import Coche`?

Comment: My import is in the first line of "miPrimerCoche", I call the folder (Coche), and from the folder I call the class. It is not good?

Comment: Try `from Coche.coche import Coche`.

Comment: Thats works perfect, is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the point of view of `miPrimerCoche.py`:

- `Coche` is a module (the folder `Coche`)
- `Coche.coche` is a submodule (the file `coche.py`)
- `Choche.coche.Coche` is the class `Coche` in the submodule `Coche.coche`

So you actually want:

```
from Coche.coche import Coche
```

The `coche` you're importing is just the (sub) module, as the error points out.

Comment: This is what I was looking for !! Thanks !